# Calculate average value of the top X rows in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column full of numbers. Every month a new number is manually added to the top of the column using "Insert Cells" -> "Shift Down".

I want to calculate the average value of the numbers in the top 3 rows of that column. This is actually easy:

```
=SUM(G1:G3)/3
```

However, this is not an acceptable solution, because as soon as I add new numbers to the top of the column, the row numbers in the formula are updated automatically to target the old numbers, making the formula essentially useless.

Is it possible to inform the formula to not update automatically, or will I need a dynamic way to select the top 3 rows somehow? (Perhaps using a query?)

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer over at webapps: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88995/33674

Basically, to avoid references to cells from updating automatically, wrap them in `INDIRECT()`.

The solution to my problem specifically was:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("G1:G3"))/3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a custom function, together with an onEdit trigger to update the value when you add a new row. Try the following:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if ( col==7 && row ==1 ){
    
    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,7).getValue() == "") {
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,8).setValue("");}
    else{ e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange("H1").setValue(avg3Values());} 
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange("H2").clearContent();
}
}

function avg3Values() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var elmt = sheet.getRange("G1:G3").getValues().flat([1]);

  var sum = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < elmt.length; i++ ){
    sum += parseInt( elmt[i], 10 );
}
  var avg = sum/elmt.length;
  return avg;
}
```

By using this functionality, cell **H1** will always calculate the average of `G1:G3` everytime you add a new `G1` cell.

You need to copy this code to an empty script. Go to `Tools => Script editor`.

Comment: @Hubro of course your way is much more preferable . But for more complex situations, Google scripts might be handy :)